# Click Gallery slider thumbs to trigger outside thumbnail links

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to trigger both .main and .thumb links, by clicking both .main and .thumb links.

```
//This code is trigger both .main and .thumb, when i click .main.
    $(".main a").on("click", function(){
    var target= $(this).attr("href");  
    $('.thumb li[data-ref="'+target+'"]').trigger('click');

});
$(".thumb li").on("click", function(){
    console.log(this);
});


//This code is trigger both .main and .thumb, when i click .thumb.
$('body').on("click",".thumb li", function(){
    var targe= $(this).attr("data-ref"); 
    $('.main a[href="'+targe+'"]').trigger('click');

});
```

how to make this code, for both link to trigger both .main and .thumb.

[DEmo](http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/cw4yG/4/)

Check Demo.

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/cw4yG/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put double quotes in your attribute selector.

```
$('.thumb li[data-ref="'+target+'"]').trigger('click');
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/cw4yG/7/

Edit : Change after more details in question and comments.

```
$(".main a").on("click", function(event){
    var target= $(this).attr("href"); 
    console.log("a: " + target);
    if(!triggered)
    {
        triggered= true;
        $('.thumb li[data-ref="'+target+'"]').trigger('click');
    }   
    else{
        triggered= false;
    }
});
$(".thumb li").on("click", function(event){
    var target= $(this).attr("data-ref"); 
    console.log("li: " + target);
    if(!triggered)
    {
        triggered= true;
        $('.main a[href="'+target+'"]').trigger('click');
    }
    else{
        triggered= false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cw4yG/10/

Comment: in this code, click work only from .main. when i click thumbs its not working.i need trigger both inside and out side links, by clicking both inside and outside links. i didnt said it before.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand what you mean by "inside" and "outside"?

Comment: .main is a slider. .thumb is some links, out side of slider. so when i click slider links i need to trigger .thumb links and when i click .thumb links, i need to trigger slider links.

Comment: can u check my demo 2. if .thumb change like this, how to change code. <li data-ref="#1"><a href="#section-1"></a></li>

Comment: Not sure about your question but have a look to this demo http://jsfiddle.net/cw4yG/13/

Comment: in your new demo, when i click .thumb, it trigger .main. but when i click .main, it doesn't trigger .thumb.

Comment: Fixed : the "a" and "[" need to be stuck. And need to parse the '#'
http://jsfiddle.net/cw4yG/14/